# N-tier Architecture in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to develop an enterprise level application using spring MVC in presentation layer and spring in Business Logic Layer and hibernate in data access layer.

But i want to keep the presentation layer in a web server, multiple business logic layer in multiple server and data access layer in another physical server that means i want to establish a n tier solution  using spring mvc.

I am able to separate the layer in my architecture. But the problem is my solution is just work on a single server. I cant do a architecture for multiple physical server.

Suppose that, from controller i use @Autowired annotation to inject the object of business logic layer. But how can i establish a system where controller talks to business logic layer over the network and business logic layer talks to data access layer over network as well.

***If anyone can describe the solution in details then it would be very helpful for me.***

Thanks...

Comment: Hi, One solution could be to take a look into message services. [Here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/) is an example with RabbitMQ, a very popular messaging framework, which can be used with Spring. This way you can connect your servers.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to divide your code quite easily. Let's call your data access layer a "Data Provider" service and business logic layer "Business Service".

Now, you have to decide what kind of network protocol are you going to use.

These days REST is the most popular one and also it is very easy to setup your REST endpoints with Spring MVC (use @RestController on the server and RestTemplate on the client). You can also use RMI if you want to really couple your services (Data Provider and Business Service) using the same Java code (interfaces, DTOs etc.)